# How to surround a specific text with <span>

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to isolate a certain letter, **v**, in a case title by surrounding it with a `<span>` tag. This single character word has always space around it, yet I've tried to do it via word boundary match in regex: `\b`

```js
(function() {
  let title = document.querySelector("h1>a");

  let a = title.innerHTML;

  let b = a.match(/\b[v]\b/i);

  console.log(b);

  title.innerHTML = a.replace(b, '<span>\1</span>');
})();
```

```css
span {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <a href="http://example.com/"> Viva v Vanuatu</a>
</h1>
```

However, the above code won't work. It doesn't select an isolated **v** character and matches any **v** character it finds first.

I want it to be like this:

```
<h1>
  <a href="http://example.com/"> Viva <span>v</span> Vanuatu</a>
</h1>
```

**No jquery please.**

Comment: `b` is not a regex, it is the matched `v`. Also, the backreference syntax is `$n`, not `\n`. You need `a.replace(/\bv\b/ig, '<span>$&</span>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

%1 is the first captured group

```js
(function() {
  let title = document.querySelector("h1>a");
  let a = title.textContent;
  title.innerHTML = a.replace(/\b(v)\b/, "<span>$1</span>");
})();
```

```css
span {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <a href="http://example.com/"> Viva v Vanuatu</a>
</h1>
```